# Sending and receiving data from Date Picker MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, frontend

I ran into a problem: when I use 2 DatePickers. It works as follows: Starting to fix the first cell with a datepicker (ddatebegin), the data is successfully changed using a patch request, getting new values. The second datepicker (dataend) and other fields in the patch request are simply duplicated from the props. However, the problem starts if you change the first datepicker in turn, and then the second one (or vice versa). This happens because during the second patch request, the previous modified date field is overwritten with the old value. Thus, the first modified datepicker again receives the previously received old value from the server. For some reason, after updating one of the datepickers, the hook does not save the new value, but is overwritten each time with the old one of the props. Individually changing each datepicker works well. How can I fix this? Thank you

```
export const MyDatePicker = (props: any) => {

    let [databe, setDatabe] = useState(props.params.ddatebegin) //HOOKS
    let [dataen, setDataen] = useState(props.params.ddateend)

    const handleChange =  async (newValue: any, flag: any, params: any) =>  {

       let ddateb3 = props.params.ddatebegin
       let ddatee3 = props.params.ddateend

        if (flag === 'dbegin') {
            let ddateb = props.params.ddatebegin //init Date
            if (ddateb !== null) {
                let ddateb2 = moment(newValue.$d).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
                    ddateb3 = ddateb2
                    setDatabe(ddateb3) //this should update the hook to use this state in another Datepicker
                    ddatee3 = params.ddateend 
            }

             let response = await axios.patch('http://10.3.6.124:3003/api/post/upd/stage', { 
                id: props.params.id, 
                id_dk: props.params.id_dk,  
                bdone: props.params.bdone, 
                ddatebegin:ddateb3, //current value from Datagrid's renderCell 
                ddateend: dataen, //HOOK state
                sotv: props.params.sotv, 
                npp: props.params.npp, 
                description: props.params.description }) 
                

    }
        
        else if (flag === 'dend') {
            let ddatee = props.params.ddateend //init Date
            if (ddatee !== null) { //если в бд имеется дата начала
                let ddatee2 = moment(newValue.$d).format('DD-MM-YYYY') //current Value dateend
                    ddatee3 = ddatee2 
                    setDataen(ddatee3) //this should update the hook to use this state in another Datepicker
                    ddateb3 = params.ddatebegin
            }


             let response = await axios.patch('http://10.3.6.124:3003/api/post/upd/stage', { 
                id: props.params.id, 
                id_dk: props.params.id_dk,  
                bdone: props.params.bdone, 
                ddatebegin: databe, //HOOK state
                ddateend: ddatee3, //current value from Datagrid's renderCell 
                sotv: props.params.sotv, 
                npp: props.params.npp, 
                description: props.params.description })
    }


    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <DatePicker onChange={(newValue) => {handleChange(newValue, props.flag, props.params)}} 
                              format='DD/MM/YYYY' 
                              value={dayjs(  
                                    (props.flag==='dbegin' && props.params.ddatebegin) || 
                                    (props.flag==='dend' && props.params.ddateend)  
                                    )}
                             
                  />        
                </LocalizationProvider>

    ) 
}
```

i tried to use hooks, but they are overwritten and become with old values again. I tried to take values from props.params.ddatebegin (and ddataend) from rendercell, but they also come not updated. I tried to use the global state and dispatch updates, it seems to be a working option, but each time you enter a day, month, or year into the datepicker, the field selection is reset, since the state is updated, and the table depends on the same state and it is also updated accordingly. the moment you enter each value.